# Capture script output to add datetime to ouput in realtime

Tags: command-line, output, realtime, capture

I'm looking to capture the output of a shell script execution in real time to enrich it with information giving the date and time.

To illustrate, I have for example a script of this type that I **must not modify**:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in 2 3 1
do
  echo "Waiting for $i seconds ..."
  sleep $i
done
```

The script produces the following output:

```
Waiting for 2 seconds ...
Waiting for 3 seconds ...
Waiting for 1 seconds ...
```

I am trying to produce the output of the type:

```
2021-06-16 11:44:48 [INFO] Waiting for 2 seconds ...
2021-06-16 11:44:50 [INFO] Waiting for 3 seconds ...
2021-06-16 11:44:53 [INFO] Waiting for 1 seconds ...
```

I use the following shell functions for formatting in a script that runs my initial script:

```bsh
function log {
   echo `date +%Y-%m-%d" "%H:%M:%S`" $@"
   if [ "$LOGFILE" != "" ]
   then
      echo `date +%Y-%m-%d" "%H:%M:%S`" $@" >>$LOGFILE
   fi
}

function loginf {
   log "[INFO] $@"
}
```

I manage very well with a while loop on a read to capture the output of my script, but I get all the lines at the same time (end of its execution) and therefore all lines have the same datetime. I try to get the lines each time the script produces a line and not at the end of the execution.

Comment: How do you call your initital script? This works well for me : `./script1.sh |  while IFS= read -r l; do loginf "$l"; done`. See also https://serverfault.com/questions/72744/command-to-prepend-string-to-each-line

Comment: `./script.sh | ts "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S [INFO]"`

Comment: I created a script that contains your two functions and then the following code: `while { read; } do loginf $REPLY; done`. Running `./script1 | ./script2` (where `script1` is your first script and `script2` the above mentioned script) gives correct output for me, ie. different timestamps.

Comment: don't need to use `echo` really, could just do `f(){ date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S [INFO] $*"; }; f one two three`

Comment: `f(){ printf '%(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)T [%s] %s\n' -1 INFO "$*"; }; f one two three` even better...

Answer (score 2):

The `ts` command from package `moreutils` does precisely what you are looking for:

```
./script.sh | ts
```

It has various options for formatting the time stamp.  For instance,

```
ts '%F %T [INFO]'
```

will give you the exact format you use in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `ts`:

```
./your_script.sh | ts
```

Of, if you need something portable that works on systems where `ts` is not installed, you can do that in a simple `while` loop using the built-in `read` command:

```
./your_script.sh | while read line; do echo "$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') [INFO] $line"; done
```